# Subscript returning Self type and unwanted need of overriding it in each subclass

Tags: swift, swift2

Is there a way to return current type from the `subscript` that would avoid overriding subscript for each subclass and this is what I'm looking for.

We can't use `Self` as the return type of the subscript because it is not allowed but maybe there is some solution?

Example:

```
class A {
    var array = [Int]()

    init(array: [Int]) {
        self.array = array
    }

    subscript(condition: (Int) -> Bool) -> A {
        get {
            return A(array: array.filter(condition))
        }
    }
}

class B: A {
    func aImB() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let objB_1 = B(array: array)
let objB_2 = objB_1[{ $0 > 3}]
print(objB_2.dynamicType) // -> will print "A" but I would like to see "B"
objB_2.aImB() // can't be called because objB_2 is of the type A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a protocol extension:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var array:[Int] {get set}
    init(array: [Int])
}

extension MyProtocol {
    subscript(condition: (Int) -> Bool) -> Self {
        get {
            return Self(array: array.filter(condition))
        }
    }
}

class A:MyProtocol {
    var array = [Int]()

    required init(array: [Int]) {
        self.array = array
    }


}

class B: A {
    func aImB() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to add `var array: [Int] { get }` to the protocol requirements for that to compile.

Comment: I have it working in a Playground (Swift 3) without this. Why would you need the protocol to know there was this property?

Comment: Because you're using the `array` property in the protocol extension. (FWIW, my Swift 3 playground also complains about this)

Comment: OK, I see. Not a problem to add this to the protocol. Not sure why this is working for me.

Comment: Your playground compiles because the extension uses the global `array` property, not the instance property.

Comment: Try removing the global declarations and you'll also get an error.